# What is the Context for a listener to get Info From a DialogFragment to the Parent Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I've been trying to search for an answer on my own but no one seems to be talking about my exact issue. It's usually a question about the RecyclerView Adapter Listener, and I've used that and it works every time.

When I run my code, I get this error,
 `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.SettingsActivity@d180f18must implement ExampleDialogListener`

which, without the `try, catch` block gives me 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.SettingsActivity cannot be cast to com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.JoinStoreDialog$EngagedDialogListener`, which doesn't make sense because I followed a tutorial and just translated it to Kotlin. I assume I am missing something about the difference in how Java and Kotlin.

**My question is, what do I put in the `listener =` line in the `OnAttach` function?**

**This is where the issue comes from.**

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            listener = context as EngagedDialogListener
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException(
                context.toString() +
                        "must implement ExampleDialogListener"
            )
        }
    }
```

**This is the Parent Activity for the Dialog**

```
package com.wereworkingonit.communitystore

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
import com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.participant.ParticipantLandingPage
import com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.user.UserLandingPage
import com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.util.FirestoreUtil

private const val TAG = "SettingsActivity"

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(),
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, JoinStoreDialog.EngagedDialogListener {
        private lateinit var contextForPreferences: Context
        private var engagedPreference: Boolean = false
        private lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences
        private var switchPreference: SwitchPreferenceCompat? = null

        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)

            switchPreference = findPreference("engage")

            androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(
                contextForPreferences,
                R.xml.root_preferences,
                false
            )
            sharedPref =
                androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    contextForPreferences
                )
            engagedPreference = sharedPref.getBoolean(AppConstants.ENGAGEMENT, false)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $engagedPreference")
            FirestoreUtil.getCurrentUser {
                switchPreference!!.isChecked = it.engagement
            }
        }

        override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
            super.onAttach(context)
            contextForPreferences = context
        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contextForPreferences)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        }

        override fun onStop() {
            super.onStop()
            androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contextForPreferences)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        }

        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            engagedPreference = sharedPref.getBoolean(AppConstants.ENGAGEMENT, false)
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause: $engagedPreference")

            if (engagedPreference) {
                //TODO: Add welcome splash for Engagement Change
                val intent = Intent(contextForPreferences, ParticipantLandingPage::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(contextForPreferences, UserLandingPage::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        override fun notThisTime(nope: Boolean) {
            FirestoreUtil.getCurrentUser {
                switchPreference!!.isChecked = nope
            }
        }

        override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?,
            key: String?
        ) {
            when (key) {
                "engage" -> {
                    val joinStoreDialog = JoinStoreDialog()

                    if (switchPreference!!.isChecked) {
                        joinStoreDialog.show(childFragmentManager, "JoinStoreDialog")
                    } else {
                        FirestoreUtil.updateCurrentUser("", null, switchPreference!!.isChecked)
                    }
                    //TODO: One way trip, or what happens if the user clicks to end engagement?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Dialog Fragment where the listener is made**

```
package com.wereworkingonit.communitystore

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment
import com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.participant.ParticipantLandingPage
import com.wereworkingonit.communitystore.util.FirestoreUtil
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_join_the_fold.view.*

class JoinStoreDialog : AppCompatDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var listener: EngagedDialogListener

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            listener = context as EngagedDialogListener
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException(
                context.toString() +
                        "must implement ExampleDialogListener"
            )
        }
    }

    interface EngagedDialogListener {
        fun notThisTime(nope: Boolean)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        sharedPreferences =
            androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                activity
            )
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_join_the_fold, null)
        view.dialog_new_store_name
        view.dialog_new_store_email
        view.dialog_new_store_password

        builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Thank You for Joining")
            .setNegativeButton("Na, Not Now") { dialogInterface, i ->
                engagedParticipant(false)
                listener.notThisTime(false)
                dialogInterface.dismiss()
            }
            .setPositiveButton("Let's Get Started") { dialogInterface, i ->
                engagedParticipant(true)
                FirestoreUtil.updateCurrentUser("", null, true)

                val intent = Intent(activity, ParticipantLandingPage::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }



        return builder.create()
    }

    private fun engagedParticipant(engagement: Boolean) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putBoolean(AppConstants.ENGAGEMENT, engagement)
        editor.apply()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Context` is your `Activity`. If you want to reference your parent fragment, you need to use `parentFragment` (or, on newer versions of Fragments, use `requireParentFragment()` to get a non-null fragment):

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        listener = requireParentFragment() as EngagedDialogListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException(
            requireParentFragment().toString() +
                    "must implement ExampleDialogListener"
        )
    }
}
```